# Why is @input_data_1 limited 128 characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

According to the documentation it should be `varchar(max)` which is about 2 billion characters. But this query:

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
""@language =N'R',
@input_data_1 ="select ptid, mridate, age, male, race, weight, height, packyrs, yrsqui, talcoh, physact, chf, chd, stroke, diabet, genhlth, ldl, alb, crt, plt, sbp, aai, fev, dsst, atrophy, whgrd, numinf, volinf, obstime, death from dbo.testpython",
@script=N'
dead = 0
notDead=0
for v in InputDataSet["a.death"]:
    if v==0:
        notDead=notDead+1
    else:
        dead=dead+1
d={"dead":[dead], "notDead":[notDead]}
OutputDataSet=pandas.DataFrame(data=d)'
WITH RESULT SETS (([Dead] int,[not dead] int));'
```

shows this error:

> Msg 103, Niveau 15, État 4, Ligne 43
>   The identifier that starts with 'select ptid, mridate, age, male, race, weight, height, packyrs, yrsqui, talcoh, physact, chf, chd, stroke, diabet, genhlth, ldl,' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

Do you know what the cause is? I'm using SQL Server Express. Would that be related?

Thank you,

Comment: @input_data_1 should likely be single quoted not double quoted.

Comment: `@language` should not have 2 double quotes before it either.

Comment: Read the error carefully. It doesn't complain about the script. It complains about the object whose name is "select ptid, mridate, age, male, race, weight, height, pac...". Double quotes and square brackets are used to quote object names. Use single quotes for strings

Answer (score 0):

Try (') instead of (")

```
@input_data_1 =N'select ptid, mridate, age, male, race, weight, height, packyrs, yrsqui, talcoh, physact, chf, chd, stroke, diabet, genhlth, ldl, alb, crt, plt, sbp, aai, fev, dsst, atrophy, whgrd, numinf, volinf, obstime, death from dbo.testpython',
```